# Is there anything to add to java buildpath so that aspects be weaved when running the project?

Tags: java, aspectj, buildpath, aop, aspect

I have a class MakeRedAspect in my project which makes red my messages:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MakeRedAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(static javax.swing.JLabel[] createMultiLabel(..))")
    public void multilabelCreation() {}

    @Around("multilabelCreation()")
    public JLabel[] changeLabelColours(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        JLabel[] labels = (JLabel[]) thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        for (JLabel label : labels)
            label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        return labels;
    }
}
```

I have added required libraries to use aspectj in my project too, and I have added the name of class in META-INF/aop.xml class too(I thought these two are enough to use an aspect class):

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>

        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.general.I18N"/>
         <aspect name="mehad.aspect.general.MakeRedAspect"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.general.AspSwingWorkerExecution"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.general.RetryAspect"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.general.AspWatchScriptExecution"/>

        <!-- <aspect name="mehad.aspect.simulink.AspWatchPort"/>-->
        <!--<aspect name="mehad.aspect.simulink.AspScannerManager"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.simulink.AspComportInterface"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.simulink.AspHeaderIcon"/>
        <aspect name="mehad.aspect.simulink.AspFileUtil"/>-->

</aspects>

<!--
    <weaver options="-verbose">
    </weaver>
-->
</aspectj>
```

But again it doesn't make my messages red and it looks like my aspects doesn't work. I remember previously it worked fine and I guess that time I had added something to java build path,What's less in my steps that my aspects doesn't make effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use load-time weaving (LTW). In order to enable LTW, you need to have the AspectJ weaving agent on the Java command line:

```
java -javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar ...
```

See [AspectJ documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving).

Comment: the [that link]http://https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving/) you see another way of load-time weaving is "Configuring Load-time Weaving with aop xml files". and I said in my question I have added the name of aspect in my aop.xml. so it seems that LTW should have been enabled.

Comment: Please read the whole LTW chapter I pointed you to, not just a small fraction of it. You need both the weaving agent and *aop.xml* in order to make it work. How should the JVM know what to do with the XML file without the loaded agent? And by the way, your link does not work.

Comment: due to the link it should that after adding that switch, but again it doesn't work! isn't there anything I'm missing? @kriegaex

Comment: Well, obviously you are doing something wrong because the aspect you took from [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29318446/1082681) definitely works. Share your project on GitHub, then I can get a full picture and help you once I get home and have some sparetime.

Comment: when I add this line: to the path: run configuration,/arguments/vm arguments it gives the error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: mehad/diaggui/toolbar/VarEditor, method: init$_aroundBody9$advice signature: (Lmehad/diaggui/toolbar/VarEditor;IDDDIZLorg/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint;Lmehad/aspect/general/I18N;Lorg/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Register pair 3/4 contains wrong type"  But when I remove that line my project works fine!  @kriegaex

Comment: As I said, you must be making a mistake. But without you publishing a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on GitHub it is hard to tell. The stack trace alone does not tell me what you have done. So either share the SSCCE or figure out your problem by yourself, with all due respect. I like to help, but I do not like to guess.

Comment: unfortunately I can't share my project, but [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783553/why-my-aspect-doesnt-do-anything) this is a simple project that again aspects don't do anything there, I would be thankful if you help @kriegaex