# Why my Aspect doesn't do anything?

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect

This is a simple class which is an aspect:

```
package aspectTest;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;


    @Aspect
    public class aspect {
        @Pointcut("execution(static String createMultiLabel(..))")
        public void multilabelCreation() {}

        @Around("multilabelCreation()")
        public String changeLabelColours(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

    String st = (String) thisJoinPoint.proceed();
System.out.println("fdfs");
    st = "st"+st;
    return st;
        }


}
```

and it's my main class:

```
package aspectTest;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class messagemethod {
    public static String createMultiLabel(final String msg) {

        return msg;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st1 = createMultiLabel("hello");
        System.out.println(st1);

    }
}
```

this is my the folder lib:
[image]

this is my aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>

        <aspect name="aspectTest.aspect"/>

</aspects>

</aspectj>
```

and this is my Run Configuration:

[image]

my problem is that when I run my main class, it just writes hello but not hello hello, which should be because of aspect. Anyone knows why my aspect doesn't make any affect?

Comment: Execution JoinPoints use full qualified methods. Did you try `@Pointcut("execution(static javax.swing.JLabel[] createMultiLabel(..))")
        public void aspectTest.messagemethod.multilabelCreation() {}` ?

Comment: I tried it and no differences occured! @SergeBallesta

Comment: If I correctly remember, the VM argument should be `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` instead of `javaagentlib`

Comment: that's javaagent:lib/ , lib is part of my path to aspectjweaver @SergeBallesta

Comment: I cannot see where lies `aop.xml` in your project configuration. And you could try to add `<weaver options="-verbose"/>` between `</aspects>` and `</aspectj>` to see weaving messages at run time.

Comment: where should I add aop.xml? @SergeBallesta

Comment: It should go in META-INF folder.

Comment: It is in my meta-inf folder, the picture is not complete. @SergeBallesta

Comment: The problem is that when I just fixes the little problems : aop.xml correctly in META-INF folder, full path for `-javaagent:`, upper case letters for classes, I can no longer reproduce the error ;-) You application should be correct, if it does not work correctly, you must have a silly typo somewhere, and without knowing exactly everything I cannot help you to find it (anyway, it is really hard to find that on a distant screen ...)

Comment: I know there would be a silly mistake, but I can't find that, I think I have share almost everything about my project, is anything more you want to know to help? @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
package test;

@Aspect
public class TestAspect {
    public static String createMultiLabel(final String msg) {
        return msg;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st1 = createMultiLabel("hello");
        System.out.println(st1);
    }

    @Around("execution(java.lang.String test.TestAspect.createMultiLabel(java.lang.String))")
    public String aroundCreateMultiLabel(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.err.println("in around before " + joinPoint);
        String string = (String) joinPoint.proceed();
        System.err.println("in around after " + joinPoint);
        return string;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you need to redefine your project type to aspect project. Compare with your .projects file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Aspects</name>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: again my main class only writes one hello in console, nothing else! @Frank M.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I copied your .project instead of mine in two of my projects, one of them works fine, but another that is above example doesn't work again. @Frank M.

Comment: @User333: With all due respect, you really need to learn how to master AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT). Many of your questions show the same pattern: You ask similar things, people provide correct answers but you cannot utilise them because your project setup its wrong. This way nobody can help you because you cannot even reproduce the correct solutions.

Comment: but I tried all the suggestions and reported the result and I know I'm not professional in aspectj but I'm trying to learn it and I think here is a place to ask and learn. @kriegaex